# SpringBoot App Registers UNKNOWN with Eureka in Brixton SR3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I'm running Spring Cloud Brixton SR3 - Spring Netflix Eureka, Spring Cloud Config and a Discovery Client app. When the client app is configured with

**eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true**
 and
 **spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true**

the app starts up registered with Eureka with a status of "UNKNOWN" and never changes to "UP". If either of those flags is set to false then the app starts up registered as "UP".

I see this series of logging when both flags are enabled/true:

```
2016-07-13 17:41:38.144  INFO 13180 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1468456898144, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2016-07-13 17:41:38.144 DEBUG 13180 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : Executing on-demand update of local InstanceInfo
2016-07-13 17:41:38.144 DEBUG 13180 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : Canceling the latest scheduled update, it will be rescheduled at the end of on demand update
2016-07-13 17:41:38.145  INFO 13180 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1468456898145, current=UNKNOWN, previous=UP]
```

How do I get the app to register as UP with both of these flags enabled/true?

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: hello-brixton

# Spring Cloud Config
  cloud:
    config:
      name: hello-brixton
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config-service

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${SERVICE_REGISTRY_URL:http://localhost:8080/eureka/}
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: can you add your application.yml here for the client app.

Comment: It's all in bootstrap.yml:

`spring:
  application:
    name: hello-brixton

# Spring Cloud Config
  cloud:
    config:
      name: hello-brixton
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config-service
    
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${SERVICE_REGISTRY_URL:http://localhost:8080/eureka/}
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true`

Answer (score 7):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but I just ran into the same problem and this was the only questions that directly matched my issue.

I am using Camden.SR2, and if you find the section Eureka’s Health Checks in the reference documentation you will see the following warning:

> `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true` should only be set in
>   `application.yml`. Setting the value in `bootstrap.yml` will cause
>   undesirable side effects like registering in eureka with an `UNKNOWN`
>   status.

That's exactly the problem. If you shift the setting of the property to the `application.yml` file it all works as expected.

Comment: Do not use `bootstrap.properties` resource file instead define application name in `application.properties` file itself.